# preg_replace all the occurrence issue

Tags: php, iframe, preg-replace

I am trying to replace all of soundcloud iframe with some shortcode. I have also created a script using preg_replace but that only works for only the first occurrence of iframe and there is also some issues which i am unable to figure out.

Here is my string

```
$con = '<iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F59701079&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>came over from Berlin for a couple of days. Mad fun that guy is!! We actually made 2 tracks during his stay here. The other one will be released soon.<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z3fIsvQDrqI" frameborder="0" width="460" height="259"></iframe>\r\n<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">GDD:</span></strong> So wild! Well were very happy youre getting the deserved attention! Tell us what you have coming up next in the Kill Frenzy world!\r\n<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>KF:</strong></span><iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F53146049&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>'
;
```

Basically what i am trying to do is to convert the

`<iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F59701079&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="166"></iframe>`

to

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/59701079"]
```

for all occurrence of the irame but the problem is that when i run this script

```
$new_con = preg_replace('/(?:<iframe[^\>]+src="[^\"]*url=([^\"]*soundcloud\.com[^\"]*))"[^\/]*\/[^\>]*>/i', '[soundcloud url="$1"]', $con);
```

$new_con  returns something like this

```
[soundcloud url="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F59701079&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee"]came over from Berlin for a couple of days. Mad fun that guy is!! We actually made 2 tracks during his stay here. The other one will be released soon.<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z3fIsvQDrqI" frameborder="0" width="460" height="259"></iframe>\r\n<strong><span style="color: #3366ff;">GDD:</span></strong> So wild! Well were very happy youre getting the deserved attention! Tell us what you have coming up next in the Kill Frenzy world!\r\n<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>KF:</strong></span>[soundcloud url="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F53146049&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=00adee"]
```

Can anyone please guide me the way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the fourth parameter:

```
$new = preg_replace('/regex/', $replace, $string, 1);
//                                        here ___^
```

It will replace only the first occurrence of the regex.

More information [here](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this by using the following

```
$new_con = preg_replace_callback('/(?:<iframe[^\>]+src="[^\"]*url=([^\"]*soundcloud\.com[^\"]*))"[^\/]*\/[^\>]*>/i', function($match) {
    $string = explode("&amp;",$match[1]);
    return '[soundcloud url="'.urldecode($string[0]).'"]';
}, $con);
```